# Machine Learning: Predict second dataset on behalf of first dataset trained classifier

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, svm, reshape

i am new to "Machine Learning" and tried to implement [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53740141/run-trained-machine-learning-model-on-a-different-dataset?rq=1) but it is unclear to me. its been 2 months i am Seducing, so please help me to resolve my error.

Actually, i am trying to:

1. *"Train svm classifer"* on **TRAIN_features** and **TRAIN_labels** extracted from **TRAIN_dataset** of shape **(98962,)** and size **98962**
2. *"Test svm classifer"* on **TEST_features** extracted from another dataset i.e **TEST_dataset** of the same shape **(98962,)** and size **98962** as **TRAIN_dataset** is.

After *"preprocessing"* of both **"TRAIN_features"** & **"TEST_features"**, with the help of **"TfidfVectorizer"** i vectorized my both features. after that i again computed the shape and size of both features i.e

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=7, max_df=0.8, sublinear_tf = True, use_idf=True)
processed_TRAIN_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(processed_TRAIN_features)
```

*"processed_TRAIN_features"* size becomes **1032665** and *"shape"* becomes **(98962, 9434)**

```
vectorizer1 = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=7, max_df=0.8, sublinear_tf = True, use_idf=True)
processed_TEST_features = vectorizer1.fit_transform(processed_TEST_features)
```

*"processed_TEST_features"* size becomes **1457961** and *"shape"* becomes **(98962, 10782)**

i know when i will *"TRAIN"* svm classifier on **processed_TRAIN_features** and when *"predict"* the **"processed_TEST_features"** using same classifier, it will produce error because *"shape"* and *"size"* of both features has become different.

what i think, the only solution to this problem is to *"reshape"* sparse matrix (numpy.float64) either **processed_TEST_features** or **processed_TRAIN_features**... i think reshape to *"processed_TRAIN_features"* is possible only as its size is less than *"processed_TEST_features"* OR there is anyother way to implement my above points (1,2). I am unable to implement [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50088190/reshape-scipy-csr-matrix) regarding to my problem and still in search that how it will become equal to *"processed_TEST_features"* w.r.t shape and size.

please if anyone of you can do this for me... thanks in advance.

Full code is below:

```
DataPath2     = ".../train.csv"
TRAIN_dataset =   pd.read_csv(DataPath2)

DataPath1     = "..../completeDATAset.csv"
TEST_dataset  =   pd.read_csv(DataPath1)

TRAIN_features = TRAIN_dataset.iloc[:, 1 ].values
TRAIN_labels = TRAIN_dataset.iloc[:,0].values

TEST_features = TEST_dataset.iloc[:, 1 ].values
TEST_labeels = TEST_dataset.iloc[:,0].values
lab_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
TEST_labels = lab_enc.fit_transform(TEST_labeels)

processed_TRAIN_features = []

for sentence in range(0, len(TRAIN_features)):
    # Remove all the special characters
    processed_feature = re.sub(r'\W', ' ', str(TRAIN_features[sentence]))

    # remove all single characters
    processed_feature= re.sub(r'\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', processed_feature)

    #remove special symbols
    processed_feature = re.sub(r'\s+[xe2 x80 xa6]\s+', ' ', processed_feature)

    # remove special symbols
    processed_feature = re.sub(r'\s+[xe2 x80 x98]\s+', ' ', processed_feature)

    # remove special symbols
    processed_feature = re.sub(r'\s+[xe2 x80 x99]\s+', ' ', processed_feature)

    # Remove single characters from the start
    processed_feature = re.sub(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', processed_feature)

    # Substituting multiple spaces with single space
    processed_feature = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', processed_feature, flags=re.I)

    #remove links
    processed_feature = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", processed_feature)

    # Removing prefixed 'b'
    processed_feature = re.sub(r'^b\s+', '', processed_feature)

    #removing rt
    processed_feature = re.sub(r'^rt\s+', '', processed_feature)

    # Converting to Lowercase
    processed_feature = processed_feature.lower()

    processed_TRAIN_features.append(processed_feature)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=7, max_df=0.8, sublinear_tf = True, use_idf=True)
processed_TRAIN_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(processed_TRAIN_features)


processed_TEST_features = []

for sentence in range(0, len(TEST_features)):
    # Remove all the special characters
    processed_feature1 = re.sub(r'\W', ' ', str(TEST_features[sentence]))

    # remove all single characters
    processed_feature1 = re.sub(r'\s+[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', processed_feature1)

    #remove special symbols
    processed_feature1 = re.sub(r'\s+[xe2 x80 xa6]\s+', ' ', processed_feature1)

    # remove special symbols
    processed_feature1 = re.sub(r'\s+[xe2 x80 x98]\s+', ' ', processed_feature1)

    # remove special symbols
    processed_feature1 = re.sub(r'\s+[xe2 x80 x99]\s+', ' ', processed_feature1)

    # Remove single characters from the start
    processed_feature1 = re.sub(r'\^[a-zA-Z]\s+', ' ', processed_feature1)

    # Substituting multiple spaces with single space
    processed_feature1 = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', processed_feature1, flags=re.I)

    #remove links
    processed_feature1 = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", processed_feature1)

    # Removing prefixed 'b'
    processed_feature1 = re.sub(r'^b\s+', '', processed_feature1)

    #removing rt
    processed_feature1 = re.sub(r'^rt\s+', '', processed_feature1)

    # Converting to Lowercase
    processed_feature1 = processed_feature1.lower()

    processed_TEST_features.append(processed_feature1)

vectorizer1 = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=7, max_df=0.8, sublinear_tf = True, use_idf=True)
processed_TEST_features = vectorizer1.fit_transform(processed_TEST_features)

X_train_data, X_test_data, y_train_data, y_test_data = train_test_split(processed_TRAIN_features, TRAIN_labels, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

text_classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', class_weight="balanced" ,probability=True ,C=1 , random_state=0)

text_classifier.fit(X_train_data, y_train_data)

text_classifier.predict(processed_TEST_features)
```

### Title EDIT: predict classification of dataset => predict dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
processed_TRAIN_features = csr_matrix((processed_TRAIN_features),shape=(new row length,new column length))
```